# Update data value with Vue from jQuery onChange

Tags: javascript, jquery, ecmascript-6, vuejs2

I'm using bootstrap-date-picker with Vue.js 2. Bootstrap datepicker doesn't update the [model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30688199/vuejs-model-binding-not-working-with-inputs-using-jquery-plugins).

But if I use the following script, I cannot access the scope to use `this`

```
loadFormProps() {
// init other stuff
$('#founding_date').change(function() {
  this.founding_date = $(this).val();
});
}
```

Modal is as following:

```
data() {
  return {
    founding_date: '01 - 01 - 2017',
  }
};
```

What will be the best solution for this, as I cannot get `vm.$data` working, and I cannot access `this` within the function.

Comment: You have two `this` inside the `change` callback function. Which `this` is not accessible? What is the console error message? What should the first `this` refer to?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to save the `this` inside some other `var` before the `onchange` JS block:

```
loadFormProps() {
// init other stuff
var that = this  
$('#founding_date').change(function() {
  that.founding_date = $(this).val();
});
}
```

Comment: Was it that easy? Thank you sir!